# The Covariance Matrix is not positive definite, even with jitter using GPy package in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gaussian-process, gpy

I'm trying to find the optimal variance and lengthscale of a 2D model using Gaussian Process (by using the GPy package in Python). I already found the code to do just that, you can see it below:

```
# sample inputs and outputs from 2d model
X2 = np.random.uniform(-3.,3.,(50,2))
Y2 = np.sin(X2[:,0:1]) * np.sin(X2[:,1:2]) + np.random.randn(50,1)*0.05
print(X2, Y2)

# define kernel, notice the number of input dimensions is now 2
ker = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=2, ARD=True)

# create simple GP model
m2 = GPy.models.GPRegression(X2,Y2,ker)
m2.optimize()
```

I tried to run the code using my own data (my data is also 2D, only larger than the data X2, Y2 in the code example) but there's an error: not positive definite, even with jitter

I also tried to add noise using `m.gaussian.noise` but it still doesn't work

Does this mean the problem comes from the numbers in my data? Anyone know any solutions for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code in plain text not an image as it is more readable.

Comment: Ok, i have already update the question